# NSTableView get rid blank space separating columns

Tags: nstableview, gridlines

I have an NSTableView with 4 columns. I also have a custom background color for each row.  The only problem is I have these ugly white spaces where the gridlines would go in both the horizontal and vertical axis.  I have both unchecked in IB, but they still show up.  How can I get rid of the vertical ones and change the color and size of the horizontal ones?

Here's what I see:
[alt text http://img815.imageshack.us/img815/9030/homex.png](http://img815.imageshack.us/img815/9030/homex.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get rid of vertical spaces but keep the horizontal ones:

```
[yourTableView setIntercellSpacing:NSMakeSize(0.0, 2.0)];
```

See [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/setIntercellSpacing:) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override [drawClipInRect](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.18/18.11/1811TableTechniques/index.html) to draw your own grid. The article I linked to modifies it so it only draws vertical gridlines. You'll have to modify it to only draw horizontal ones instead, but the basic strategy is the same: By overriding it, you can make it not draw vertical lines by simply not including the code for it.