# How to hide NSTableView's white outline on a black window?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

So what I've been trying to do was to put a NSTableView on a black background.  However, for some kind of reason there's this white outline that wraps the NSTableView like this:

[image]

What I've got here is a translucent window with a subclassed NSTableView so that I can customize it's color.  Alternating rows are turned on.

I've tried setting the grid color and background to a color with 0 alpha value, however nothing changes.  Does anyone know why or how I can fix this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in Your NSTableView horizontal grid is turned on. You can turn off it in *Attributes inspector* and change colors also (grid and background).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot link is broken, so it’s hard to tell what you’re looking for exactly.

This answer might interest you, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4349459/135712

`[yourTableView setIntercellSpacing:NSMakeSize(0.0, 0.0)];`