# Change separator color to background or remove it from NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am looking to remove the separator color in View based `NSTableView`.

It looks like this :

[image]

For UITableView there is a method `setSeparatorColor:` but not for NSTableView.

Solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032802/nstableview-get-rid-blank-space-separating-columns

Comment: @Harikrishnan: already checked but that only didn't work for me, I had to increase the viewSize as well.

Answer (score 15):

I did this as:

Changed the Intercell spacing to :

```
[aTableView setIntercellSpacing:NSMakeSize(0, 0)];
```

And changed the height of the the cell, set view's width to `30.f` , the cell being drawn is of `35.f`.

Now it is perfect, screen shot :

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For `NSTableView`, Interface Builder has settings for `Horizontal Grid`, `Vertical Grid`, and `Grid Color`.  These are reflected in the API as `-setGridStyleMask` and `setGridColor`.

They do exactly what you want.

```
[table setGridColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[table setGridStyleMask:NSTableViewGridNone];
```

Comment: I wanted transparent color.

Comment: If you set the grid to none, the only color will be your background color, just as you asked for. If you had wanted it to be another color, you could of course set it to a different partially transparent colour. Any colour can have a transparency set (alpha).

Comment: I checked with this way, still it shows in view based tableview :(

Comment: OK, I tested this out with a view based table. Cocoa draws the grid on top of the table cell. So the only colour that would make the grid disappear would be 0% alpha.  But setting the grid to none doesn't draw the grid at all, so that can't be visible. So it could only be that it was gaps between the views that were showing for you (but not me). I guess that's why intercell spacing and/or changing the height of your cell views worked for you.

Comment: not only intercell, i had to implement both (increaed the view height too)

Answer (score 5):

Answer for Interface Builder :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I could mention that in view based tables NSTableRowView is responsible for drawing the seperators. So in the inspector for the table you set it the grid to "None" and implement `drawSeparatorInRect:` in your NSTableRowView subclass, which in your case would mean leaving it empty.

Comment: yes your point of subclassing is correct. But I did it without that overhead. As you have seen in my solution.

Comment: If you turn off grid views in an NSTableView, drawSeparatorInRect: doesn't get called.